# Algorithm to merge a small sorted list into a larger sorted list, without duplicates, in linear time

Tags: c++, list, merge

I have two lists with varying amount of elements, containing at least one duplicate each. I'm looking to merge the smaller list into the larger one, in linear time at worst.

I can figure this out by using a third temporary list, but I specifically need to merge the smaller list into the larger, not create a third.

Here's a function that takes in a list and merges them using a new list "temp". Note: this uses a custom List, but you can assume the insert method works the same at the STL version.

```
void mergeNoDups(const List<Object> & rhs)
    {
        List<int> temp;

        for (const_iterator iter = this->begin(), iter2 = rhs.begin(); iter != this->end() || iter2 != rhs.end();)
        {
            if((iter != end()) && iter2 == end() || (*iter < *iter2))
            {
                temp.push_back(*iter);
                ++iter;
            }
            else if (*iter == *iter2)
            {
                ++iter2;
            }
            else if (*iter > *iter2)
            {
                temp.push_back(*iter2);
                ++iter2;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Given inputs:**

list1 = [0 1 2 5 6]

list2 = [3 4 5 7]

**list1 should be:**

list 1 = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]

Any tips?

Comment: Suppose you wanted to insert *one new element* into a sorted list, so that the result will be a sorted list (e.g. the new element is in the right place) in linear time and with creating a temporary list. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Beta How does this translate to this problem though?

Comment: Because if you can locate the insertion point and insert (or not insert should the node already exist) one node, all you need to do do it again and again and again until the lists are merged. Just remember to start looking for the new insertion point at after the node you just inserted (or didn't insert).

Answer (score 0):

You can do in-place merge in linear time given that insert operation is O(1), which is typically true for all list implementations.

There is not much difference with your solution. The algorithm is very similar:

Let's have the following notation: *smaller list* is the list that we do not mutate. *Larger list* is the list that we mutate by inserting elements from the smaller list.

- Start with two iterators pointing to the beginning of each list
- If values at both iterators are the same, increment iterator of the smaller list (skip duplicates)
- If the value at iterator of the larger list is greater (or we reached the end of the larger list), then insert the value from the smaller list before it, increment iterator of the smaller list
- Otherwise, increment iterator of the larger list.
- Terminate loop if iterator of the smaller list reached the end.

The code is below:

```
#include <list>

template<typename T>
void mergeNoDups(std::list<T>& larger, const std::list<T>& smaller)
{
    typename std::list<T>::iterator itl = larger.begin();
    typename std::list<T>::const_iterator its = smaller.begin();

    while (its != smaller.end())
    {
        if (itl == larger.end() || *itl > *its)
        {
            larger.insert(itl, *its);
            ++its;
        }
        else if (*itl == *its)
        {
            ++its;
        }
        else // *itl < *its
        {
            ++itl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this code, except I'm still only passing in the one list as a parameter and using "this->" to reference the other list. AKA I'm calling the function like this: list2.mergeNoDups(list1). I'm getting a "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)" error. Using the example larger = 0 1 2 5 6 and smaller = 0 1, it looks like "its" is going past the end of the smaller list.

Comment: Here is URL to online c++ compiler http://cpp.sh/42ufb
It seems to run correctly with your example. Maybe the problem is with custom List implementation?

Comment: Insert should insert an element before the element specified by the iterator. Is it implemented that way?

Comment: Can you share the List implementation with the modified *mergeNoDups* function?